# Unable to merge PR due to a commit message not prefixed with JIRA number

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working on branch A and want to merge the PR into the master.
But the merge button in the bitbucket is disabled with a message -
`Commit dbf... was not associated with at least one Jira issue`
This is because I made a commit with a message without the Jira number as a prefix
to the commit message (All other commits are fine)

I am not sure what to do in this case.

**Some Thoughts:**

- Create a new branch from the master and put all the changes from branch A into it as a single commit. (Not sure if there is an easy way to do this)
- I have heard of squashing commits, but not sure how useful will that be in this case. But I guess even squashing won't change the commit history of the branch so it will still contain the commit with the missing Jira message.

Comment: Both of your "thoughts" seem kind of heavy-handed. If the problem is the commit message of one commit, why don't you just change the commit message for that one commit?

Comment: @Guildenstern's comment is the solution, but I would also recommend using a git hook to prevent this situation in the future: https://medium.com/bytelimes/automate-issue-numbers-in-git-commit-messages-2790ae6fe071

Comment: @TonyArra Rebasing is causing conflict several times. Which is causing a lot of effort in resolving the conflict.

Comment: @pensee that's a scenario where squashing or an interactive rebase would help you. You can `edit` the first commit that introduces the conflict in your branch, and then `reword` the commit with the bad commit message. The exact solution is going to be very specific to your branch history, so you're better off reading the docs: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Also, if you don't really care about preserving the branch history, you could just do a `git reset --soft` and rewrite your entire branch as a single commit.